# Parallel vectors in vector field

Tags: calculus

Let **F** be a conservative vector field where every vector is parallel to $y = x$. What can we deduce about the potential function $f$? And justify.

Could someone please help with this question and the justification. My thought process was that there had to be some scalar $k$ in $f$ if they were parallel, but I wasn't sure how to justify it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming $F$ is a vector field in the $XY$-plane. If the vectors in the vector field are parallel to $x=y$ it means that the level curves of the potential are straight lines parallel to $x=-y$. Therefore your potential has the form $f(x,y)=h(x+y)$ for some $h$.

Formally, suppose $f(x,y)$ is parallel to the vector $(1,1)$, it means that $f(x,y)=(P,Q)=(k(x,y),k(x,y))$. Since $f$ is conservative you have
$$
\partial Q/\partial x=\partial P/\partial y
$$
or
$$
\partial k/\partial x=\partial k/\partial y
$$
which implies that the directional derivative of $k$ in the direction $n=(1,-1)$ is zero, that is
$$
\partial k/\partial n=\nabla k\cdot (1,-1)=0.
$$
As a consequence, $k$ is a constant along lines $x+y=const$, $k(x,y)=g(x+y)$. Now we find a potential
$$
F(x,y)=\int_{(0,0)}^{(x,y)}Pdx+Qdy=\int_0^xg(t)\,dt+\int_0^{y}g(x+s)\,ds=
$$
(changing variables)
$$
=\int_0^{x}g(t)\,dt+\int_x^{x+y}g(u)\,du=\int_0^{x+y}g(u)\,du=h(x+y).
$$
This is a possible formal argument for something that is pretty clear geometrically. Hope it helps.

Comment: HI, thanks for you post. Wouldn't it mean $f(x,y) = -h(x + y)$

Comment: There is no difference. $f$ is some function of $x+y$ only, you can call it $h$ or $-h$.

Comment: @ GReyes ok that makes sense. I am struggling to make a proof for it.

Comment: I will add a formal proof in my answer.